# Regex to capture string between slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture show name which is between `/` `/`

`http://www.voot.com/shows/`**splitsvilla-s09**`/1/411756/love-turns-sour/425120`

I tried

```
window.location.href.split('/')[4];
```

How to capture the highlighted part?

Comment: Have you tried `split()` or `match()`. If yes, add the code.

Comment: `split('/')[4]` works fine on your input string

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
var string = "http://www.voot.com/shows/splitsvilla-s09/1/411756/love-turns-sour/425120"

var matches = string.match(/(\/[\w+-]+)/g);

console.log(matches[2].replace("/",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var url = "http://www.voot.com/shows/splitsvilla-s09/1/411756/love-turns-sour/425120";
var name = /shows\/([^\/]+)/.exec(url)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str  = "http://www.voot.com/shows/splitsvilla-s09/1/411756/love-turns-sour/425120"
str.match(/shows\/\w+/g).join('').split('/')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, a proposal with [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
var url = 'http://www.voot.com/shows/splitsvilla-s09/1/411756/love-turns-sour/425120';
console.log(url.match(/shows\/([^\/]*)/)[1]);
```